# Mongo/Express: How to return all documents in collection if no query params are passed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, request

I'm trying to return all documents from my Mongo collection if no query parameters are passed. Currently I have 3 optional query parameters that could be passed by the user.

```
localhost:3000/api/projects

//should return all projects. Currently this is returning []
```

```
localhost:3000/api/projects?id=1

//should return projects with id of "1". Working properly.
```

```
localhost:3000/api/projects?name=myproject

//should return projects with name of "myproject". Working properly.
```

```
localhost:3000/api/projects?created_by=John

//should return projects created by "John". Working properly.
```

Within my route, I'm trying to determine my request has any query values. If it does not, then I want to return all documents in the collection. As stated above, this is not returning anything.

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    if (req.query !== '') {
        const project = await Projects.find({
            $or: [
                { _id: req.query.id },
                { name: req.query.name },
                { created_by: req.query.created_by }]
        });
        res.json(project);
    }
    else {
        const project = await Projects.find();
        res.json(project);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your api handler like this:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res)=>{
  let options = {...req.query};
  try{
    const project = await Projects.find(options);
    res.json(project);
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }

});
```

This will fetch the documents on the basis of your query. If there is no query params req.query will be empty object and hence it will find all documents.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: I am glad i could be of help.  Please upvote if u like the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
        let searchQuery = {}

        if(req.query.id){
            searchQuery._id = req.query.id
        }

        if(req.query.name){
            searchQuery.name = req.query.name
        }

        if(req.query.created_by){
            searchQuery.created_by = req.query.created_by
        }

        const project = await Projects.find(searchQuery);
        res.json(project);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

const id = req.query.id || null;
const name = req.query.name || null;
const created_by = req.query.created_by || null;

const query = { id, name, created_by };
const project = await Projects.find(query);
res.json(project); 
});
```

I didn't test it, but I would solve your problem this way.